# How can a test verify that a particular function is executed

Tags: c++, googletest

I need to verify that a (heavy) function is only executed on the correct input. Is there some easy way to do this?

Currently I see 2 ways forward

1. Modify the function with an extra parameter only used in testing
2. Wrap the function in something that can keep track of execution and use that to replace the function

1 is rather ugly and I don't know how to do 2

Example:

For example I would like to test that heavy here isn't executed when a<=3

```
void function_to_test(int a){
  if(a>3){
    heavy();
  }
}
```

Comment: If you need to verify on the correct input, check the input's correctness in the beginning of the function

Comment: Use a mocking framework (e.g. GoogleMock, Trompeloeil, Hippomocks) to mock the heavy function and set expectations on it.

Comment: And maybe add some code to your question because it's not clear

Comment: +1 for using a mocking framework, IF you really need to check that a function is called. However, by doing so you are testing the implementation, not the functionality, i.e. you are setting an expectation on _how_ the code does something, not _what_ it does.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example how to write unit test using gtest.

```
class Turtle {
virtual ~Turtle() {}
virtual void PenUp() = 0;
virtual void PenDown() = 0;
virtual void Forward(int distance) = 0;
virtual void Turn(int degrees) = 0;
virtual void GoTo(int x, int y) = 0;
virtual int GetX() const = 0;
virtual int GetY() const = 0;
};

#include "gmock/gmock.h"  // Brings in Google Mock.
class MockTurtle : public Turtle {
 public:
  ...
  MOCK_METHOD0(PenUp, void());
  MOCK_METHOD0(PenDown, void());
  MOCK_METHOD1(Forward, void(int distance));
  MOCK_METHOD1(Turn, void(int degrees));
  MOCK_METHOD2(GoTo, void(int x, int y));
  MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(GetX, int());
  MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(GetY, int());
};

#include "path/to/mock-turtle.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
using ::testing::AtLeast;                     // #1

TEST(PainterTest, CanDrawSomething) {
  MockTurtle turtle;                          // #2
  EXPECT_CALL(turtle, PenDown())              // #3
      .Times(AtLeast(1));

  Painter painter(&turtle);                   // #4

  EXPECT_TRUE(painter.DrawCircle(0, 0, 10));
}                                             // #5

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  // The following line must be executed to initialize Google Mock
  // (and Google Test) before running the tests.
  ::testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

And more documentation is in below link

https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/ForDummies.md

Comment: You should explain the analogy between you example and the original problem. What would be this "heavy" function in your example? You and I understand but maybe it is not obvious to the person who asked the question. Also, you did not demonstrate checking of input arguments.